# List of all image based ResourceObjects?

Tags: resource-management, resourceobject

Is there some way to search across content types in ResourceObjects? Something like this would be nice:

```
ResourceSearch[<|"ContentTypes" -> "Image"|>]
```

[image]

Comment: The DataRepository provides this kind of thing so it should be possible. Look at the DownValues. My guess is the API it calls will provide this.

Comment: @M.R. Did you find your answer? Care to share?

Comment: @rhermans not yet... but I will definitely post if I find a solution

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this method:

```
ResourceData;
ResourceSearch[{"ContentTypes"->"Image"}]
```